# Summarize Dataset ydata_profiling ProfileReport

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, profiling, pandas-profiling

I've trying to use CustomTkinter + Pandas + ydata ProfileReport to make a simple system that load the dataset, transform with pandas and make a Profile Report with ydata_profiling.

The program works well on all of the functions, but it didn't summerize the dataset.
I've this function:

```
    def report(self,data):
        report = ProfileReport(dados,title='Relatório Inicial')
        report.to_file('./ReportCriado.html')
```

This fuction receive a dataset like:

`TAG1                      time 0     11.8  2023-10-01T12:41:30.933Z 1     12.3  2023-10-01T12:46:30.933Z ...    ...                       ... 7703  13.5  2023-10-31T13:33:51.155Z 7704  13.5  2023-10-31T13:38:51.155Z`

But, it doesn't create a report. On my prompt it returns:
`Summarize dataset:  14%|██████████████████████                                                                                                                                   | 1/7 [00:00<00:00,  9.84it/s, Describe variable:TAG1]` 
Is this a RAM problem? IDE problem?
Thank you, guys!

I am currently using VSCode, but it sometimes runs, sometimes it doesn't.
When I run ProfileReport on simpliest Apps it runs well.

But, running on a highest application, doesn't